# Regular Expression Problem: Match in Context

Tags: regex, delphi, hierarchical-data, pcre, dfm

I have a structured file with hierarchical text which describes a GUI in Delphi (a DFM-File).

Let's assume I have this file and I have to match all "Color = xxx" Lines, which are in the context of TmyButton (marked), but not those in other context. Within the TMyButton-Context there won't be a deeper hierarchical level.

```
object frmMain: TfrmMain
  Left = 311
  Top = 201
  Color = clBtnFace
  object MyFirstButton: TMyButton
    Left = 555
    Top = 301
    Color = 16645072           <<<<<<MATCH THIS
    OnClick = ButtonClick
  end
  object MyLabel: TLabel
    Left = 362
    Top = 224
    Caption = 'a Caption'
    Color = 16772831
    Font.Color = clWindowText
  end
  object Panel2: TLTPanel
    Left = 348
    Top = 58
    Width = 444
    Height = 155
    Color = clRed
    object MyOtherButton: TMyButton
      Left = 555
      Top = 301
      Color = 16645072         <<<<<<MATCH THIS
      OnClick = ButtonClick
    end
  end
end
```

I tried it two days long with many, many different tries.
Here some of my incomplete pieces of the pattern:

```
/^[ ]{2,}object [A-Za-z0-9]+: TmyButton\r\n/mi  <<<Matches the needed context
/^[ ]{4,}Color = [A-Za-z0-9]+\r\n/mi            <<<Matches the needed result
/^[ ]{2,}end\r\n/mi                             <<<Matches the end of the context
```

(I don't know why, but I had to use "\r\n" instead of "$"...). I need to put this together, but ignoring the other lines except other "object xxx: yyy" and "end" Lines....

I would be glad to have some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching a line in a complex context requires a regex feature called lookaround, if you want or have to do it with a single regex. Specifically, you'd need variable-length lookbehind which PCRE doesn't offer.

So there are two possibilities:
Use a scripting approach like Rorick suggested or use a regex that matches everything from the start of your needed context until the actual match, and extract that using a capturing group. That could be done with

```
[ ]{2,}object \w+: TMyButton\r\n.*?^([ ]{4,}Color = \w+[ \t]*\r\n)
```

(brackets around the space inserted for clarity). Your match would then be in capturing group `\1`

Nested structures generally are not well suited for regexes (better for parsers) but if you're sure of the structure of your data as you mentioned, it might work OK.

Comment: variable-length lookbehind: thats what I tried fist... I think I need to do some scripting. Now I will search first for the context using /^[ ]{2,}object \w+: TMyButton\r\n(^[ ]{4,}.+\r\n)+^[ ]{2,}end\r\n/mi and then within this match search for /^[ ]{4,}Color = \w+\r\n/mi

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you try to create single regexp for this. There is no reason to do so.

1. Just find line with pattern `object [A-Za-z0-9]+: TmyButton`
2. Then check each next line against `Color = [A-Za-z0-9]+` until you find it or reach `end` keyword.
3. Repeat steps until end of file

If you try to modify a bulk of source files, you could use some scripting for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not PCRE, but a good alternative for software archeology.

You could at any time use AWK, if you do this from a command prompt. The script would look like this:

```
BEGIN       { inObj = 0; } // Not really necessary
/TMyButton/ { inObj = 1; }
/end$/      { inObj = 0; }
/^[ ]{4,}Color = [A-Za-z0-9]+\r\n/ && inObj == 1
            { //do whatever you need to do
              print $3;
            }
```

AWK can be found all over the internet. I would try [GAWK](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).